# Is a child raised bilingually more likely to have a language delay?

Tags: language

I remember reading that long ago the American Psychological associations were wary of advising a child to be raised bilingually because it can cause a delay in language learning for the child.  As I recall this recommendation was later reconsidered when it was determined that bilingual children were usually able to catch up on language later and often had additional learning/language skills.  However my question concerns whether there is an initial language delay to begin with.

As late as 2000 the [AAFP released a paper saying](http://www.aafp.org/afp/1999/0601/p3121.html):

> A bilingual home environment may cause a temporary delay in the onset
> of both languages. The bilingual child's comprehension of the two
> languages is normal for a child of the same age, however, and the
> child usually becomes proficient in both languages before the age of
> five years.

However, some sources offer the opposite view, that there is no language delay in bilingual children and claim that research backs up their view.

[An article on the subject](http://Although%20many%20parents%20believe%20that%20bilingualism%20results%20in%20language%20delay,%20research%20suggests%20that%20monolingual%20and%20bilingual%20children%20meet%20major%20language%20developmental%20milestones%20at%20similar%20times.) mentioned a 2006 report of the Center for Applied Linguistics said:

> "Although many parents believe that bilingualism results in language
> delay, research suggests that monolingual and bilingual children meet
> major language developmental milestones at similar times."

[Another article quoted](http://www.babycenter.com/0_raising-a-bilingual-child-the-top-five-myths_10340869.bc#articlesection2) Ellen Stubbe Kester, president of Bilinguistics saying:

> Research indicates that bilingualism does not cause delays in either
> speech or language acquisition

Does research say that there is no delay for children raised in a bilingual environment?

Comment: I believe there is no consensus on this in the research community.

Comment: From personal experience, it depends whether the parents set up a system (eg language 1 during dinner, language 2 the rest of the time). I have absolutely no backing up info for this.